# Parsing special characters in JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

I'm now parsing with `NSJSONSerialization`

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"]];
NSError *jsonError = nil;
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];


NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = (NSDictionary *)jsonObject;

[self setTableData:jsonDictionary];
```

But it won't parse my JSON because of special characters in the JSON like the letter **'ü'** when i remove the **'ü'** from the JSON it's working correclty. I tried the code above and:

```
options:utf8...
```

Does anyone know how i can fix this?

Comment: Your string is improperly encoded/converted.  If properly encoded and the UTF8 gets converted to Unicode then JSON will have no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using NSString with which you can explicitly specify encoding. Ex:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:webURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

You can then convert the NSString object to NSData and then do the JSON serialisation..

Answer (score 0):

Try to change **NSJSONReadingMutableContainers** with **NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves**. This solved me similar problem.

Comment: Can you verify that your data is in UTF-8 format? If not, convert it first before calling NSJSONSerialization

Comment: @Frenck -- Read the data into an NSString before JSON decoding and see what you get.